# how to write xpath for parameterised variable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I have to write an xpath for the below xml snippet:

```
<div class="flex-item flex-container-horizontal flex-align-center sf-element sf-element-page-tab sfpc-even" title="S1M0D barchart" tabindex="1">
<span class="sf-element sf-element-text-box sfpc-first sfpc-last sfpc-odd">S1M0D barchart</span>
</div>
```

In the xpath, I have to add a variable tabName which shall replace the title in the xpath:

```
tabName = S1M0D barchart
//span[contains(text(),"tabName"]
which is nothing but //span[contains(text(),"S1M0D barchart")]
```

I am not sure how to write the xpath since the double quotes (") is treating the variable tabName as a string and is not getting replaced during execution.

Comment: Selenium doesn't support XPath 2.0. You should use programming language features to pass your variable value to XPath expression

Comment: String xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\""+tabName+"\"]"  & then use this xpath wherever you want to use . (for-ex driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format`, you need to wrap the variable in single quotes

```
String tabName = "S1M0D barchart";
String.format("//span[contains(text(),'%s')]", tabName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for your time. I figured out the answer to this post.
We can write the xpath like "//span[contains(text(),\"" + tabName + "\")]"